# Script for opening GNU screen or similar with lots of the same process

Tags: bash, shell, gnu-screen

I'd like to type (at bash)

```
./start_screen.sh 3 some_cmd with parameters
```

and have it start up GNU screen with three separate, independent copies of the running command `some_cmd with parameters` running in bash in three separate vertically-split windows. What's the best way to do this? Does someone know how to put the pieces together?

(This is so I can run three worker daemons in the background and monitor them in one window.)

NOTE: alternatives to screen are just fine. In fact, at worst, it's ok if you can't interact with the windows apart from killing them all at once. (I mostly just want to see the outputs in parallel.)

Comment: I'm not sure there is a way to do this. I've investigated opening or configuring screen to open multiple screens via script before, and I'm fairly sure screen is strictly interactive. I don't think there is a provided way to do this. If you can find it, let me know :)

Comment: alternatives to screen are fully acceptable too (tmux?)

Answer (score 3):

`screen` executes commands from `$HOME/.screenrc` on startup by default.

You can override this with the `-c` option.

Create a temporary file with the commands you want, then run `screen -c your-file`.

This won't get the default settings you already have in `$HOME/.screenrc` unless you copy them to the temporary file.

(Disclaimer: I haven't tried this.)